# Supremum and infimum of set with absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am looking for the supremum and infimum of $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2-5 \lvert x \rvert + 4 <0\}$. I consider two separate cases ($x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$) and find that $x \in (-4; -1) \cup (1;4)$, so $\text{sup}A = 4$ and $\text{inf}A = -4$. This seems almost too easy. Is it?

Comment: Why too easy?  If your intervals are correct, then so are your answers.

Comment: It is a general trait of questions formulated in a deceptively easy form to turn out to be more challenging than basic quadratic functions, at least from my experience.

Comment: True, we often are so deceived.

Comment: $x^2 - 5x + 4 <0; x \ge 0$ means $(x-4)(x-1)<0$ so $(x-4) <> 0$ while $(x-1) >< 0$ but $(x-4)>0; (x-1)<0$ is contradictory so $x \in (1-4)$.$x^2 + 5x + 4 <0; x < 0$ means $(x+4)(x+1)<0$ so $(x+4) <> 0$ while $(x+1) >< 0$ but $(x+4)>0; (x+1)<0$ is contradictory so $x \in (-4,-1)$.  Okay, that's easy, but by no stretch of the imagination would I say it is "too easy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.
Write $A= \{x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) < 0\}$ with $f(x) = x^2 -5|x| + 4$.

For any $x<0$ $x\in A \iff f(x) = x² + 5x + 4 < 0$.

For any $x\geq 0$ $x\in A \iff f(x) = x² - 5x + 4 < 0$.

Basic calculus now gives, that $A = (-4,-1) \cup (1,4)$. Indeed it is just that simple as you said.

If you want to make this more plausible to you, calculate the derivative of $f$ and see that $f^\prime(x) <0$ for $x < -4$ and $f^\prime(x) > 0$ for $x > 4$. Together with having a root at $x = \pm 4$ you can conclude, that $f(x) > 0$ for $|x| > 4$.